# filter the table by the user status isactive or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, boolean, kendo-ui

model

```
 public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
```

linq statement pseudo code

```
 var userstatus = Users.Select(e => e.IsActive).Distinct().select();
   if (userstatus(bool) is DBNull)
        {
            e.Item.Text = "inactive";
            e.Item.Value = "0";
        }
        else if ((bool)["Bool"])
        {
            e.Item.Text = "active";
            e.Item.Value = "1";
        }
```

select it by dropdown list

```
 <select >
     <option value="">All</option>
     <option id="active">Active</option>
      <option id="inactive">InActive</option>
      </select>
```

filtering

```
    if($("#active").val()){

        $filter.push({ field: "IsActive", operator: "eq", value: true });
    }
     if($("#inactive").val()){

        $filter.push({ field: "IsActive", operator: "eq", value: false  });
    }
```

so the linq is wrong and also the filtering, any one can help me or done this before

I want to filter the column by the user status is active or not

Comment: What's doing the leg-work for the filtering? I see that you have an object defined to receive key:value pairs, but I don't know what you're using to filter. I'm not familiar with kendo-ui, so perhaps it's that? Also, what's the error you're receiving? Or, are you not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the filtering change your logic like this

```
if($("select").val() == 'active'){

        $filter.push({ field: "IsActive", operator: "eq", value: true });
    }
    else if  if($("select").val() == 'inactive'){

        $filter.push({ field: "IsActive", operator: "eq", value: false  });
    }
```

Comment: but the value is not right here, for value is 0 stand for false, 1 stand for true, and if i enter 0, will be give me numeric value